# Radare2 Flare-on 2015, Why results different?

Tags: radare2

Learning how to use radare2 while getting the feel for crackmes.  Following the steps for Flare-on 2015 Challenge One on hxxp://solidsec.blogspot.com/2015/10/ctf-fire-eye-flareon-2015-challenges-1-3.html (change hxxp to http, not enough cred to embed the link after adding the two pictures :-( sorry)

- Load exe using r2 -A
- go to address 0x00402140
- px 0x18

[image]

I get all FFs.

The documentation of the site shows actual values versus all FFs as seen below:
[image]

Why?

Problem with my copy of radare2 (running off of Remnux) or not loading the exe right into r2?  I realize the number of variables here is just about endless, but hoping it is just something simple that I'm missing due to being new to RE.  Thanks!

Comment: Radare2 from remnux is probably 5 years old, use radare2 from github version : `git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2 && cd radare2 && ./sys/install.sh`

Comment: @Maijin, that was it exactly.  Remnux was using a version from 2014-04-10.  I've installed the latest and it works as expected!  Thanks and yes, I should have checked that first.  Lesson learned

Comment: In order for you to validate an answer I have converted the previous comment in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radare2 from remnux is probably 5 years old, use radare2 from github version : `git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2 && cd radare2 && ./sys/install.sh`

Answer (score 1):

the first file needs to be extracted to get another executable and then you can find the email address that is needed to pass the challenge in the extacted executable

```
2015_FLAREOn_Challenges\1>r2 -A i_am_happy_you_are_to_playing_the_flareon_challenge.exe
[0x00401000]> s 0x402140 ; px 24 ; e io.cache = true ; wox 0x7d @0x402140:24 ; px 24
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x00402140  1f08 1313 0422 0e11 4d0d 183d 1b11 1c0f  ....."..M..=....
0x00402150  1850 1213 531e 1210                      .P..S...
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x00402140  6275 6e6e 795f 736c 3070 6540 666c 6172  bunny_sl0pe@flar
0x00402150  652d 6f6e 2e63 6f6d                      e-on.com
[0x00402140]>



 md5 of the extracted executable = 
    $b="";(([system.security.cryptography.md5]::Create("md5")).computehash( 
( gc -Encoding byte arg1))) | %{$b+="{0:X2}" -f $_} ;$b

7C0F16DE595AE03E2928D3FA6B73B235
```

Comment: You can use `rahash -a md5`, `#md5` or `!md5sum` within radare

Comment: @blabb, nice trick with wox.  Thanks for posting your solution to the exercise.